# I want to replace text in FieldCodes (Word Document). How can i use variable for that?

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I want to replace text in FieldCodes (Word Document). How can i use variables for that?

This is for a Word Doc with links to other Word Doc's (IncludeText Link). When i change the link one by one without variable it works. When i use variables for it, it doesn't.

```bsh
$Desktop = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")

$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Document = $Word.Documents.Open("$Desktop\Test.docx")

$Test = 147   # (Test.GetType() = Int32)

$Document.Fields(147)   #Works
$Document.Fields($Test)   #Works
$Document.Fields($Test).LinkFormat.SourceFullName = ""  #Works

$TextLinks = $Document.Fields | Where-Object Type -eq "68" | Select -expand Index
#TextLinks contains value 147 and 149

$Test = $TextLinks[0]  # is also 147 (Test.GetType() = Int32)

$Document.Fields($Test)   #Doesn't work (runs indefinitely)
$Document.Fields($Test).LinkFormat.SourceFullName = ""  #Doesn't work (runs indefinitely)

147..149 | Foreach { $Document.Fields($_).LinkFormat.SourceFullName } #Doesn't work (runs indefinitely)
```

Update:

Now it runs with `$Test = [INT]$Textlinks[0]`. Thanks Cindy!
But when i try a loop it hangs with te second value

```bsh
$Desktop = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")

$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Document = $Word.Documents.Open("$Desktop\Test.docx")

$TextLinks = $Document.Fields | Where-Object Type -eq "68" | Select -expand Index
$ItemNumber = 0
$End = $TextLinks.Count

Do {
    $Item = [INT]$Textlinks[$ItemNumber]
    if ($Document.Fields($Item).LinkFormat.SourceFullName -match "Test") {
        $Link = $Document.Fields($Item).LinkFormat.SourceFullName -replace "Test", "TestTest"
        $Document.Fields($Item).LinkFormat.SourceFullName = $Link
        $Document.Fields($Item).LinkFormat.AutoUpdate = "True"
        $ItemNumber += 1
    }
} Until ($ItemNumber -eq $End)

$Document.Save()
$Word.Quit()
$OUT=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Word)
```

Update 2:

Code below runs fine but i dont understand why the code above doesn't

```bsh
$Desktop = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")

$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Document = $Word.Documents.Open("$Desktop\Test.docx")

$TextLinks = $Document.Fields | Where-Object Type -eq "68" | Select -expand Index
$ItemNumber = ($TextLinks.Count)-1
$End = -1

Do {
    $Item = [INT]$Textlinks[$ItemNumber]
    if ($Document.Fields($Item).LinkFormat.SourceFullName -match "Test") {
        $Link = $Document.Fields($Item).LinkFormat.SourceFullName -replace "Test", "TestTest"
        $Document.Fields($Item).LinkFormat.SourceFullName = $Link
        $Document.Fields($Item).LinkFormat.AutoUpdate = "True"
        $ItemNumber -= 1
    }
} Until ($ItemNumber -eq $End)

$Document.Save()
$Word.Quit()
$OUT=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Word)
```

Comment: **Remark**: `$TextLinks` appears to be a collection. A collection can't be used as an index. Does this work: `$Document.Fields($Test[0])`? If that's not the issue: I'm not conversant in Powershell so I need to ask a couple of questions for clarification. What is 147? Is it the index value of the Fields collection in the document (the 147th field from the beginning)? Could you please provide the full field code of this field (what you see when you toggle using Alt+F9)?

Comment: `$Document.Fields($Test[0])` does work, `$Document.Fields($TextLinks[0])` doesnt. How is it possible that $Test does not work while it contains only 1 value? So $Test shouldnt be a collection? $TextLinks i know it is, thats why i tried $Test with 1 value of $TextLinks

Comment: Hangs with the second value... Which line fails? Does it hang or is there an error? If the latter, what is it?

Comment: TextLinks doesn't work because it's not an index value, it's a Field object. Quite possibly you could loop this collection directly, instead of referring to Fields[index]?

Comment: The document has 298 Field Codes, im for now only interested in the "IncludeText" ones (Type 68). There are only 2 of them for now (Index 147 and 149). Link when toggling Alt+F9 is: `{ INCLUDETEXT "\\\\Fileserver\\Test\\TRANSPORT WITHOUT PACKING.docx" }` in folder \\Fileserver\TestTest i have a document with the same name but different text so i want to replace "Test" with "TestTest" (2x, Index 147 & 149) . I dont know how to loop directly. Maybe i can toggle Alt+F9 through powershell and do a find and replace but dont know if thats possible

Comment: i think something went wrong with the loop because it is working now. Thanks for the help